# How to check if a string is included in an array? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js, include

Basically I am trying to make a discord bot to make trivia questions by showing an embed and awaiting the answer, I have put the answers in an array in a separate file, the `possibleAnswersF` is the array that includes the answers that give you 5 points, and the `possibleAnswersT` is the array that includes the answers that give you 10, and possibleAnswers is the array that includes all of the answers, I tried to use `possibleAnswersF.includes(collected)` but it wouldn't work, I tried to make collected an array and use `includes()` the other way but it jumped to `catch()` instead.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
//const talkedRecently = new Set();
const Characters = require('../../triviacharacterlist');
const points = require('../../points.json');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    commands : ['trivia', 't'],
    minArgs : 0,
    maxArgs : 0,
    callback : (msg, arguments, text) => {
      function TriviaGuess(possibleAnswers, possibleAnswersF, possibleAnswersT, CharacterImgDir) {
        const guessCharacterString = "Guess character bo3";
        let pointAmt1 = 5;
        let pointAmt2 = 10;

        const triviaEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#008fff')
            .setTitle(guessCharacterString)
            .setImage(CharacterImgDir)

        msg.channel.send(triviaEmbed)

        const filter = m => possibleAnswers.some(answer => m.content.toLowerCase().includes(answer));
        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                    const fivePoint = `**Congrats**, ${collected.first().author} you got **5** points for guessing the character only!`;
                    const tenPoint = `**Congrats**, ${collected.first().author} you got **10** points for also guessing the series/game!`;
                        if (possibleAnswersF.includes(collected)) {
                            msg.channel.send(fivePoint);
                            points[msg.author.id] = {
                                points: points[msg.author.id].points + pointAmt1
                            };
                            fs.writeFile('./points.json', JSON.stringify(points), (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (possibleAnswersT.includes(collected)) {
                            msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                            points[msg.author.id] = {
                                points: points[msg.author.id].points + pointAmt2
                            };
                            fs.writeFile('./points.json', JSON.stringify(points), (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err)
                                }
                            });
                        }
            })
            .catch(collected => msg.channel.send('too bad u took too long ya 3am'));
      }
      var characterRandom = 0;//Math.floor(Math.random() * 0);
      
      if (characterRandom == 0) {
        TriviaGuess(Characters.CreeperVariants, Characters.CreeperVariantsF, Characters.CreeperVariantsT, Characters.CharacterImgs.creeperimg);
      }
  }
}
```

The other file that has the arrays:

```
const CreeperVariants = [
    'creeper',
    'creeper minecraft',
    'creeper mc'
]

const CreeperVariantsF = [
    'creeper'
]

const CreeperVariantsT = [
    'creeper minecraft',
    'creeper mc'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collected` is a Collection extending Map, not a string. You would need to check `collected.first().content`. Use `Array#some()` with `String#includes` to check if any of the array elements are found in the string.

```
if (possibleAnswersF.some(ans => collected.first().content.includes(ans))) {
   // Your code
}
```